# Building a plugins-based code in Python

Tags: design, design-patterns, python

I have a program which perform different actions depending on the plugins that are passed. For example, `python main.py -m foo -m bar` will perform the actions of `foo` and `bar`.

The structure of the directory is:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── docker-compose.yml
├── entrypoint.sh
├── modules
│   └── foo.py
│   └── bar.py
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
└── settings.yaml
```

And in `main.py`, I have a function for each of the plugins. Assume the following:

```
def foo():
    ...

def bar():
    ...

if args.all or 'foo' in args.modules:
    foo()
elif args.all or 'bar' in args.modules:
    bar()
```

This works but there must be certainly a better way to work with plugins , because as the number of module grows, having a function and an `if` for each one doesn't look like a good option.

What's the recommended way to do an implementation like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can place some requirements on the modules, then you can make it quite dynamic. The requirements that you must place on the modules are at least

1. The name of the file must match the name passed in the `-m` argument
2. The file must be placed in the `modules/` folder
3. The module must support the functions that the main application will want to call on it. These functions will have a name and arguments as defined by the main application (so independent of the module).

With these requirements, you can use the python module `importlib` to dynamically load your modules as python modules and call functions on them.
For the `--all` option, you can just iterate over the files in the `modules/` folder.

Comment: setuptool's entrypoints mechanism can also be used to implement plugin systems, rather than using importlib directly

Comment: I ended up following this approach

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to multiple if-statements could be a dispatch table:

```
modules = {
  'foo': foo,
  'bar': bar,
}

if args.all:
  args.modules = modules.keys()

for module_name in args.modules:
  try:
    module = modules[module_name]
  except KeyError:
    ...
  module()
```

Some command line argument parsers such as Click have built-in support for running multiple commands, so you don't have to write this dispatching logic yourself.